# Ошибка: Функция searchInside не найдена

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Опишу ситуацию получения ошибки.

Есть карта, на нее подгружаются объекты с json файла.

После прогрузки есть кнопка с функцией "обвести область". То есть при нажатии мы начинаем рисовать область, в которой хотим отфильтровать / просмотреть точки.
Сделано через произвольную область на карте. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_custom вот из этого примера.

Когда мы отпускаем кнопку мыши и формируется сама область - подключается код поиска объектов.
Брали вот с этого примера https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle

У нас получилось:

```
var objectsInsideCircle = objectManager.searchInside(geoObject);
objectsInsideCircle.setOptions('preset', 'islands#blueIcon');
```

Мы еще окрашивает их в другой цвет (точки).

Но при этом коде мы получаем ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: objectManager.searchInside is not a function
```

Я думаю, что где-то и как-то нужно отдельно подключить эту функцию... но не понимаю почему и как. По идее сразу все они должны быть подключены при генерации карты...

Просьба подсказать.

---

UPD

Получение objectManager

```
        var myPlacemark,
            myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [<?php echo $mapCenter; ?>],
                zoom: 6,
                controls: ['smallMapDefaultSet']
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            }),
            objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
                // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
                clusterize: true,
                // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
                gridSize: 64
            });

        // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
        // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
        objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
        objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/exchange/yandex_map/yandex_map.json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            objectManager.add(data);
            //console.log(data);

            var objectMapFull = data;

            jQuery.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/exchange/ajax/object_sidebar_map.php',
              data: {'objects' : objectMapFull},
              success: function(data){
                console.log(1);
                jQuery('.page-map .search-map-sidebar .objects').replaceWith(data);
              }
            })

        });
```

Comment: Как вы получаете переменную objectManager?

Comment: Обновил описание вопроса. Там привел код, как получаю objectManager

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом работать не будет, потому что ObjectManager работает только с сырыми данными, а geoQuery только с геообъектами.

Проще воспользоваться функцией [setFilter](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter) в ObjectManager-е.

Comment: Я понимаю как отфильтровать параметры метки. То есть по options каждой метки. Тут более менее описывается.
Но никак не пойму как по координатам проверять.
[coordinates] - тут массив координат получается
geoObject - тут массив данных, которые с геообъектами...

По идее по [coordinates] мы должны проверять получается.

Но вот как?
var objectsInsideCircle = objectManager.setFilter('geometry == '+[coordinates]);
console.log(objectsInsideCircle);
Это явно неверно, так как так нельзя приравнивать геометрию...

В итоге я хочу получить попавшиеся объекты с данными как у objectManager

Comment: К сожалению не могу выстроить для себя логику работы. Если с option еще более-менее и то... непонятно пока мне как получить формат типа objectManager, то с геометрией беда. Не могу понять. И примеров в мануале и песочнице не увидел....

Comment: Еще момент смущает. По идее setFilter убирает метки, что не вошли в условие. Что как раз не подходит. Так как другие метки должны оставаться. Именно поэтому смотрел на searchInside

Comment: И момент. Если смотреть на ваш ответ, то я не понимаю почему возникает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: objectManager.searchInside is not a function То есть саму функцию он найти не может... Если бы была проблема с данными, то и ошибка была другой.